# Statistical measures of a function of a 2D matrix of random variables

Tags: probability-or-statistics

Im new to *Mathematica*, and I have been searching online without success an answer to what should be an easy question. I want to define a function $f$ on, say, $n$ independent random variables and compute statistics about $f$ (such as expected value and variance).

Say I have a matrix $m=\{\{a,b,c\},\{b,d,f\},\{c,f,e\}\}$ and I compute `Det[m]`. I will get a function on these variables. I want to say they are Bernoulli 0 - 1 with probability $p$. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: The answer is "Yes". The "how" depends on what you want to do next with the `Det`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For example:

```
xa = Array[x[Sort@{##}] &, {3, 3}];
k  = TransformedDistribution[Det@xa, 
           Thread[Union@Flatten[xa] \[Distributed] BernoulliDistribution[1/2]]];
MatrixForm@xa
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And then

```
Probability[x > 1/4, x \[Distributed] k]
Variance[k]
Expectation[x, x \[Distributed] k]

(*
5/64
35/64
-(3/8)
*)
```

Comment: @DanielMontealegre I don't follow what you mean by your comment about a symmetric matrix. Could you perhaps edit your original question to include more details on your intended use? Otherwise it seems to me that Belisarius showed how you could accomplish what you originally asked.

Comment: @MarcoB If you look at the definition of $m$ in the question ... I overlooked it also at first :)

Comment: Ha! I had misread / misunderstood the question. I see now what Daniel meant now.